# Instant static HTML server in the cloud

Tags: html, jsbin

Is there a site I can open in my browser like Codepen, JSbin, etc that actually serves my code instead of just runs it in the current window?

There are cloud IDEs and so on but I just want a way to throw up some code as easily as Codepen but puts it on a static server and gives me the URL.

Comment: You mean like pastebin?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are looking for? An editor that gives you a website? You could always use github pages or give https://divshot.com/ a try its for static pages. This doesnt really make sense. You could just use like a testing domain or something to serve up static code...

Answer (score 0):

You talk about using Codepen in your question. Currently, Codepen **does** provide a way to serve a static version of anything you post, with a static URL. To get the URL, open the Codepen pen, and look for the button that says "Editor" (at the time of posting this, it has an aqua bar near it). Click on the Editor button, and look for "Full Page". Just to the right of "Full Page", there should be a small link you can click that reads "Get URL".

I'm unsure if this answers your question, as the question is a tad unclear, but I believe I've done what I can to parse what you're asking.